MATH staircase kern on \bigvee doesn't work?
I was experimenting a bit with MATH staircase kerns in LaTeX. In particular I was trying to add, using fontforge, a staircase kern to \bigvee in the bottom right corner (for better subscript placement). However, while on a (blackboard bold) W the staircase kern worked perfectly fine, I couldn't get it to work for the \bigvee.
(For details see below.)
Am I doing something wrong? Or is this issue caused by something related to \limits/\nolimits somehow?
Details/Steps

I'm working with new-computer-modern (NewCMMath-Regular.otf).
Open in fontforge, goto the wedge symbol: uni22C1 (there is also a uni22C1.v1 which I tried to kern too)
Right click -> Glyph info -> TeX & Math -> open Math Kerning
Under the Graphical tab in the Bottom Right display, draw two corner points very close to the vee (so the effect should be easy to see): 
Click OK, OK, then generate the OTF font (I named it NewCMMath-Regular-staircase.otf).

LaTeX:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Regular-staircase.otf}
%\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Regular.otf}

\begin{document}
    $\bigvee_{x}$
    %\[\bigvee\nolimits_{x}\]
\end{document}

Output:

No kerning happening as far as I can tell; output looks identical to that with \setmathfont{NewCMMath-Regular.otf} used instead.
(I also tried with \Uchar"22C1 instead of bigvee; same result.)
When doing the same thing with the blackboard bold W (u1D54E.bb, and enable StylisticSet=3) the staircase kern works perfectly fine.
